# Packet detection using regex

Tags: c#, regex, performance

I'm new to regular expressions, and I need to write a set of regular expressions that match different data packet formats.

My problem is, usually I only need to look for the start and ending parts of the packet to distinguish between them, the data in between is irrelevant.

**What's the most efficient way to ignore the data between the start and end?**

Here's a simple example.
The packet I'm looking for starts with $CH; and ends with #

Currently my regex is  `\$CH;.*?#`

It's the .*? I'm worried about.  Is there a better (or more efficient) way to accept any character between the packet header and ending character?

Also, some of the packets have \n chars in the data, so using . won't work at all if it means [^\n].

I've also considered `[^\x00]*?` to detect any characters since null is never used in the data.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\$CH;.*?#` is fine and should be quite efficient. You can make it more explicit that there should be no backtracking by writing it as `\$CH;[^#]*#`, if you like.

You can use `(.|\n)` or `[\w\W]` to match truly any character--or even better, use the [RegexOptions.Singleline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) option to change the behavior of `.`:

> Specifies single-line mode. Changes the meaning of the dot (`.`) so it matches every character (instead of every character except `\n`).

Comment: I like \$CH;[^#]*# best so far.  Question: if I used \$CH;[^#]*?# instead, would the question mark be purely redundant?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\$CH;[\s\S]*?#
```

Answer (score 1):

To detect start of line/data use `^` anchor, to detect the end, use `$` anchor:

```
^start.*?end$
```

Be aware that `.*?` may fail to match newlines, one option is to change it for `[\s\S]*?`

Comment: Can't.  The packet I'm trying to match is in the middle of an essentially random data set, so there is nothing to anchor to.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking the initial and terminal sequences separately using anchored regular expressions.

Comment: Can't.  The packet I'm trying to match is in the middle of an essentially random data set, so there is nothing to anchor to.

Comment: @CSharperWithJava OK, I did not realize that. In that case, if packets cannot be empty, use `\$CH;[^#]+#`.